# Rendering multiple webpages in memory using QtWebKit breaks on second page, why?

Tags: python, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I'm using PyQt4's QtWebKit to a render a webpage in memory, because I need the javascript executed as I need to retrieve an embedded flash video element. Currently the code I'm using looks like this:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import QWebSettings, QWebPage

class Render(QWebPage):
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        QWebPage.__init__(self)

        # Settings
        s = self.settings()
        s.setAttribute(QWebSettings.AutoLoadImages, False)
        s.setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptCanOpenWindows, False)
        s.setAttribute(QWebSettings.PluginsEnabled, True)

        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))
        self.app.exec_()

    def _loadFinished(self, result):
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()
        self.app.quit()

def get_page_source(url):
    r = Render(url)
    html = r.frame.toHtml()
    return html
```

Now this works OK, though it is extremely slow to initialize(taking anywhere between 5-30 seconds to start), however it only works OK for a single page. Meaning that on the first webpage, my final output looks like this:

```
<div>
    <embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" src="/player.swf" width="560" height="440" style="undefined" id="mediaplayer" name="mediaplayer" quality="high" allowfullscreen="true" wmode="opaque" flashvars="width=560&amp;height=440&amp;autostart=true&amp;fullscreen=true&amp;file=FILELINK"></embed>
</div>
```

But on successive attempts, it looks like this:

```
<div>
    <font>
        <u>
            <b>
                <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/">ATTENTION:<br>This video will not play. You currently do not have Adobe Flash installed on this computer. Please click here to download it (it's free!)
                </a>
            </b>
        </u>
    </font>
</div>
```

What is happening here that I'm not aware of?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to retrieve - just 'file=FILELINK'?

Comment: @HughBothwell Yes, but that is not a problem. I need to know why it breaks after successive attempts to retrieve pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your javascript interpreter only kicks in on the first page; the second page loads but never gets its javascript run; but that's irrelevant to your real problem, which is that the name of the video file is hidden in the chunk of code that looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var googleCode = 'czEuYWRkVmFyaWFibGUoImZpbGUiLCJodHRwOi8vd2lsbGlhbS5yaWtlci53aW1wLmNvbS9sb2FkdmlkZW8vMDA5YzUwMzNkZmYyMDQ3MmJiYzBjMjk2NmJjNzI2MjIvNGZmNGQ2ZDYvd2ViLXZpZGVvcy9iZTVjYWI2YjcxNmU0OWExZjFiYzc3NGNlMjVlZDg0Yl93YWtlci5mbHYiKTs=';
    eval(lxUTILsign.decode(googleCode));
</script>
```

If you call up a javascript console and run `lxUTILsign.decode(googleCode);` you get

```
"s1.addVariable(\"file\",\"http://worf.wimp.com/loadvideo/2e368b70f8577ad167087530fc73748d/4ff4f5df/web-videos/35e78d1932b24f80ae3a9210fce008c4_titanic.flv\");"
```

The *bad* news is that lxUTILsign is thoroughly obfuscated; the *good* news is, that's irrelevant, because it is simply a base64 decoder, and Python already has one (batteries included, baby!).

```
import base64
import urllib2
import re

def get_video_url(page_url):
    html = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    match = re.search("googleCode = '(.*?)'", html)
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError('googleCode not found')
    googleString = base64.b64decode(match.group(1))
    match = re.search('","(.*?)"', googleString)
    if match is None:
        raise ValueError("didn't find video url")
    return match.group(1)

url = 'http://www.wimp.com/titanicpiano/'
print get_video_url(url)
```

returns

```
http://worf.wimp.com/loadvideo/8656607f77689f759d54b4ec7207152d/4ff4ff9c/web-videos/35e78d1932b24f80ae3a9210fce008c4_titanic.flv
```

Comment: Welp, that's one way of doing it and quite a lot faster than actually rendering the page. I didn't know where it was getting the url from. Thanks a bunch.